# req.url.replace(/\/?(?:\?.*)?$/, '') node js

Tags: javascript, node.js

I'm referring to a book and it has code I can't understand:

```
        http.createServer(function(req,res){        
         // normalize url by removing querystring, optional        
         // trailing slash, and making lowercase        
         var path = req.url.replace(/\/?(?:\?.*)?$/, '').toLowerCase(); 
        }
```

I have a problem in the following line:

```
var path = req.url.replace(/\/?(?:\?.*)?$/, '').toLowerCase();
```

What is that first argument of replace method?

Comment: It's a regex literal: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Regular_Expressions

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The first argument is the pattern, a *regex* on what to look for, and the second argument is to what to replace the instances with. In this case, `\/?` is the `/` character with zero or one instance of it, and `(?:\?.*)?` not to capture the piece where it has `?` zero to unlimited times.